# mongodb upsert performance optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using Nodejs with mongodb

I have this api which is responsible for dumping data into Reporting collection

Now payload data comes in bulk as array

This data is coming from
Different sensors that is installed on different stores

Currently I have 5 Million records in Reporting collection

The api should dump this data in Reporting collection in fastest way possible, but before that there should be no duplication in the database based on

**tenantId, typeId, reportingType, storeCode, hour, startTimestamp, endTimestamp**

it should always consider and keep the latest records, the old records should be either deleted or updated with new one

Currently I am performing Upsert

Now this logic is working perfectly fine.

But the main issue here is that this operation takes so much time and CPU utilization goes to 97% for mongodb

Here is my code:

```
importReportingData: async function (params) {

    try {
        
        if (!params.payload || !params.payload.length) return {statusCode: 3, message: 'payload is missing.', response: {params: params});

        const bulkOps = [];

        if (params.payload && params.payload.length) {
            
            for (var i = 0; i < params.payload.length; i++) {
                
                const data = params.payload[i];
                const reportingType = data.reportingType;

                const query = {
                    tenantId: data.tenantId,
                    reportingId: data.reportingId,
                    reportingType: data.reportingType,
                    storeCode: data.storeCode,
                    hour: data.hour,
                    startTimestamp: { $gte: new Date(data.startTimestamp) },
                    endTimestamp: { $lte: new Date(data.endTimestamp) }
                };

                const update = {
                    $set: {
                        tenantId: data.tenantId,
                        reportingType: data.reportingType,
                        storeCode: data.storeCode,
                        reportingId: data.reportingId,
                        hour: data.hour,
                        month: data.month,
                        year: data.year,
                        dayName: data.dayName,
                        week: data.week,
                        startTimestamp: new Date(data.startTimestamp),
                        endTimestamp: new Date(data.endTimestamp),
                        traffic: data.countValue,
                        createdAt: new Date()
                    }
                };

                const bulkOp = {
                    updateOne: {
                        filter: query,
                        update: update,
                        upsert: true
                    }
                };

                bulkOps.push(bulkOp);
            }
        }

        console.log("Bulk Write Initiated....!");
        await Reporting.rawCollection().bulkWrite(bulkOps);
        console.log("---> Bulk Write Done <---");

        return {statusCode: 200, message: 'Success', response: {});
    } 
    catch (err) {
        
        return {statusCode: 400, message: err.message, response: {});
    }
}
```

Now is there any way to optimize this?

**Edit**

I have indexes created on following:

**tenantId, typeId, reportingType, storeCode, hour, startTimestamp, endTimestamp**

startTimestamp and endTimestamp is actually the complete timestamp for hour start and end

E.g

startTimestamp: 2023-06-30 13:00:00

endTimestamp: 2023-06-30 13:59:59

Currently I am sending a payload size of 500 objects after 5minutes. Even when I send 50 objects per payload, it takes time as soon as dataset grows. Of course not much as 500 objects payload but still takes lot of time and with in that period CPU is on 100+ percent usage

Comment: I guess the first question here would be - do you have an index to support finding the data that needs updating? What does `.explain()` for a (single) update report?

Comment: @user20042973 have a look at question on Edit part

Comment: Those are all single field indexes? Create a compound index that basically includes all of the fields in your query (coincidentally in the order that you have them written above) and let us know if that helps

Comment: Could you give me some example?

Comment: Run a command similar to `db.getSiblingDB("<DBNAME>").Reporting.createIndex({ tenantId: 1, reportingId: 1, reportingType: 1, storeCode: 1, hour: 1, startTimestamp: 1, endTimestamp: 1 })` in the shell connected to the database replacing the `<DBNAME>` and `Reporting` text as needed

Comment: should i drop current created indexes? and how is that different from what I did now with indexes? I created one by one like this: `Reporting.createIndex({ tenantId: 1 })` `Reporting.createIndex({ reportingId: 1 })` etc..

Comment: The database will typically only use one index per operation. It will be _much_ more efficient for it to use a compound index with all of the query predicates at the same time. I can't comment on whether any or all of the current indexes should be dropped because we don't know what the other queries are. These update operations should use the new index regardless of the presence of the others (since it is much more efficient)

Comment: So technically the other indexes I created on same columns individually wont effect alongside with compound index

Answer (score 0):

> But the main issue here is that this operation takes so much time and CPU utilization goes to 97% for mongodb
>
> Now is there any way to optimize this?

Overall you haven't definitively provided enough information for us to confidently determine the root of your problem. But per the edit and the comments we can take an educated guess at the problem and its associated resolution. In addition to the elevated CPU utilization, we have two other clues. The first is the query portion of the `update` itself, namely:

```
const query = {
  tenantId: data.tenantId,
  reportingId: data.reportingId,
  reportingType: data.reportingType,
  storeCode: data.storeCode,
  hour: data.hour,
  startTimestamp: { $gte: new Date(data.startTimestamp) },
  endTimestamp: { $lte: new Date(data.endTimestamp) }
};
```

And then the indexes present on the collection:

> I have indexes created on following:
>
> `tenantId`, `typeId`, `reportingType`, `storeCode`, `hour`, `startTimestamp`, `endTimestamp`

It sounds like these are all single field indexes. In that situation then, for each of them, the database can consider a possible plan that resembles the following:

- Scan the index for the matching values of that single field. For example to find all documents with the appropriate `hour`.
- For all of those matches, retrieve the full document and apply *all* of the other query conditions (`tenantId`, `reportingType`, `startTimestamp`) to filter out documents that don't match.

What is *probably* happening here is that it is the *combination* of all of the query predicates that are selective as opposed to a single one. This effectively leaves the database with no good query plans, as every option needs to scan many (potentially orders of magnitude) more documents than those that are actually targeted for modification. This is very wasteful and, assuming that much of the data set is in memory, very CPU intensive.

The solution here is to provide an index that the database can use to create an *efficient* ("good") execution plan. Creating such an index will look similar to the following command in a shell session:

```
db.getSiblingDB("<DBNAME>").Reporting.createIndex({ 
  tenantId: 1, 
  reportingId: 1,  
  reportingType: 1, 
  storeCode: 1, 
  hour: 1, 
  startTimestamp: 1, 
  endTimestamp: 1 
});
```

You should replace `<DBNAME>` and `Reporting` as needed to match your environment. This index will allow the database to almost perfectly retrieve index keys and documents associated with documents that are targeted by the operation. That approach will be much more efficient and will likely reduce CPU utilization (and duration) of the operation significantly (dependent on the selectivity of the query on this collection).

Further troubleshooting would require the output of `.explain("allPlansExecution")` for the operation.

> So technically the other indexes I created on same columns individually wont effect alongside with compound index

If I understand [your question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589103/mongodb-upsert-performance-optimization#comment135099171_76589103) correctly, then the answer is "yes". For the most part, databases typically only use a single index per query/operation. The aforementioned compound index will almost certainly be used by this operation, and it makes the single field index on `{ tenantId: 1 }` likely redundant and safe to remove. We cannot say anything about whether or not the other indexes can be removed as information about the other queries in your workload is not available. You can find some more general information on the topic [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/).

Answer (score -2):

looking at your code, i don't know the payload size, i would break it into small parts, for example 100 by 100
other think create index with your query attributes
your code in batch of 100 it would be something like this(i don't execute)

```
importReportingData: async function (params) {
  try {
    if (!params.payload || !params.payload.length) {
      return {
        statusCode: 3,
        message: 'payload is missing.',
        response: { params: params },
      };
    }

    const batchSize = 100; // Number of items to process per batch
    const payload = params.payload;

    const totalBatches = Math.ceil(payload.length / batchSize);

    for (let batchIndex = 0; batchIndex < totalBatches; batchIndex++) {
      const startIndex = batchIndex * batchSize;
      const endIndex = startIndex + batchSize;
      const currentBatch = payload.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

      const bulkOps = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < currentBatch.length; i++) {
        const data = currentBatch[i];
        const reportingType = data.reportingType;

        // Your existing code for generating the bulk operation

        bulkOps.push(bulkOp);
      }

      console.log(`Bulk Write Initiated for Batch ${batchIndex + 1}....!`);
      await Reporting.rawCollection().bulkWrite(bulkOps);
      console.log(`---> Bulk Write Done for Batch ${batchIndex + 1} <---`);
    }

    return { statusCode: 200, message: 'Success', response: {} };
  } catch (err) {
    return { statusCode: 400, message: err.message, response: {} };
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the reasoning or justification for why this approach would be superior/faster than the current one?

Comment: I don’t think this is going to matter since  currently i am sending 500 objects per request. Even after reducing to 50 onjects takes time and CPU usage goes to 100+ percent, of course the time span for High Cpu usage is less than 500 objects but still it keeps growing as soon as database grows.

Comment: @user20042973 because with smaller batches the use of processing and memory is smaller, but in this case as it sends 500 in 500 it won't make any difference..